# Update tables when cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
----- s.op_id= ------
| S |----------| OP |
----- op.op_id ------
                  |
                  | op.op_id = j.op_id
                  |
                -----
                | J |
                -----
```

An oracle database has three tables `journey`, `op_profile` and `special`.

`journey` has two columns `journey_id` *(primary key)* and `op_id`,
`op_profile` has primary key `op_id` and
`special` has a column `op_id` which is a *foreign key* on `op_profile` and a further column `s_id` which is the tables primary key.

I have tried to update all the `op_id` columns to equal the `journey_id` column of the `journey` table with the following sql usin sql developer:

```
UPDATE (SELECT special.op_id, journey.journey_id, op_profile.op_id AS op
        FROM special, journey, op_profile
        WHERE special.op_id = journey.op_id AND journey.op_id = op_profile.op_id)
SET op_id = journey_id, op = journey_id;
```

which gives the following error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

which seems to say that this operation is failing because of the keys of each table.

Is this possible in this way, or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible using two update statements:

```
update s
    set op_id = (select j.journey_id
                 from j
                 where j.op_id = s.op_id
                );
```

and:

```
update op
    set op_id = (select j.journey_id
                 from j
                 where j.op_id = op.op_id
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes on the following (if not available before)

1. special.op_id
2. journey.op_id
3. op_profile.op_id

This problem happens when it cannot obtain a stable set of rows for update.